# Complex many to many relation?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am working on a project which has a complex data structure which I'm not sure how to parse. I have been trying to build a solution but each idea I come up with I get a feeling that it won't have 100% accuracy. If there was an already existing well known and tested method then I can rely on that.

**So here is an example:**

Imagine a store has a list of promotions, each promotion has it's own list of whether or not it can connect with other promotions.  I need to come up with stacks of promotions which can connect with each other, not leaving any promotions out at all.

So lets say I have promotions, A, B, C, D. I will get a list telling me which promotions stack with which promotions:

A -> B = S (stackable)

A -> C = N (non stackable)

A -> D = S

B will also have its list and D will have its list. I cannot assume that not having an N means it is stackable, but I can assume that not having an S means it is not stackable.  There may be anywhere from 1 to infinite promotions.

I need to make sure I get every possible combination of promotions available.  In the end I need an array of all the combinations (preferably unique combinations) but even non-unique is fine if every combination is listed.  If you know the name for such a problem you can answer with just the name, you don't need to edit my question, just a name is enough for me to search it myself more on Google.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be formulated as [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem).

You need to construct a graph where the promotions are vertices and there is an edge between two vertices if the promotions can be stacked. A possible promotion is now a complete subgraph or a clique, which is a subgraph where each vertex is connected to each other vertex in subgraph.

This is an NP-complete problem but if your system is not too large it should be feasible to solve.

A brute force algorithm is quite straight forward. There are two special cases.

1. First all vertices are cliques (each promotion alone)
2. All the edges connecting two vertices are cliques (list of two promotions)

Then for rest

```
k = 2 .. (number of vertices)
  v in vertices
    if (v.neighbors.size >= k)
      s in distinct combination of k neighbors of v and v 
        if each vertex in s has a link to other vertices in s add s to the list
```

As can be seen from the algorithm it gets slower if there are lot of links as the number of combination grows exponentially.